# Navigation view for Tablet landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create an app for both tablet and Mobile. for mobile i am displaying menu by using Navigataion view.is it possible to use same view in landscape mode for tablet with menu always opened (Like Gmail app in Landscape mode)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using a DrawerLayout on mobile. You can create a new layout file with the same name in the layout-sw600 (or another size you prefer) folder, and not place the NavigationView in a DrawerLayout, but in a regular LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. In your Activity / Fragment you might have to some checks when you want to call the drawer, because it won't exist on tablets.